# Back-Up / Download-Feature is missing

Tags: microsoft-teams

1. The problem i found is, that there is no Back-Up / Download-Feature for my Team
2. I have tried to download all the Files that were uploaded in my Team because a lot has accumulated there. There should be a Button under the drop-down Menu "Further Options" called "Download files" which provides to download a Zip-File with all the files in the given folder tree.

Remember: Who doesn't back up his files has to rewrite them. And there is always one fool in a team who deletes or cut files so that they are gone forever...

Answer (score 1):

Recall that "Teams" is a bit of a mix of products under the covers. In this regard, "Files" is *actually* content stored in SharePoint Online, behind the scenes. That means that you have the capabilities of SharePoint available, like the normal and the admin "recycle bins". In addition, you can use any 3rd party SharePoint backup solution.